# How to create a command “Select a group” in a telegram bot?

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8, [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk).
I created an inline "Select Group" button.

```
public function handle()
{
    $inlineLayout = [
        [
            Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Choose a group', 'callback_data' => 'data']),
        ]
    ];

    $reply_markup = Keyboard::make([
        'inline_keyboard' => $inlineLayout,
        'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'one_time_keyboard' => true,
    ]);

    $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Click on the button to select a group.', 'reply_markup' => $reply_markup]);
}
```

How to hang an event on this button so that you can select a group in the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that everything is simple.
It is necessary to add the url parameter:

```
$inlineLayout = [
        [
            Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Choose a group', 'callback_data' => 'data', 'url' => 'https://t.me/all2all_bot?startgroup=c']),
        ]
    ];
```